# How to cache pods IPs and access it with http request

Tags: caching, kubernetes, ips

I have an idea to implement and i need to create a cache for the pods IPs in a kubernetes cluster and then use an http request to access the cached IPs.
I'm using Golang and as i'm new in this field i would be so grateful if anyone have an idea how to implement that. I searched a lot in internet but i didn't find any simple examples to use as a start.

I started with a piece of code to get the podlist  what i need is to put he podlist in a cache, like that each time a request arrives it will use the cache insead of using the kubernetes api o get the IPs.

```
kubeClient, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(cfg)

if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error building kubernetes clientset: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(2)}
options := metav1.ListOptions{
        LabelSelector: "app=hello",}
podList, _ := kubeClient.CoreV1().Pods("namespace").List(options).  What i need is to create a cache for the IPs of hello pods for-example and when an http request arrive to my http server, the request will use directly the cached IPs
```

I appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You should not access pod by their IPs. They are not persisted across pod restarts.

Comment: Any  suggestions please?

Comment: What is the use case you are trying to solve?

Comment: To minimize the latency when receiving each time a new request i need to use the Ips from a cache instead of  trying to get the ip of the pod from the kubernetes API

Comment: that's not how K8s work. Requests are forwarded based on the `Service` generally and they are redirected towards the matching pods based on label/selectors.

Comment: I Know but i want to communicate directly with the pod IP , that's why i need to create a cache in golang but i don't know from where to start.

Comment: Please consider upvoting useful answers and accepting answers that solved your problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

There's only one correct answer to such question: **Leave it. It's a very, very bad idea.** Believe me, with such solution you'll only generate more problems that you will need to solve. What about updating such cache when a `Pod` gets recreated and both its name and IP changes ?

`Pod` in **kubernetes** is an object of ephemeral nature and it can be destroyed and recreated in totally normal circumstances e.g. as a result of scaling down the cluster and draining the node `Pods` are evicted and rescheduled on a different node, with completely different names and IP addresses.

The only stable manner of accessing your `Pods` is via a [`Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) that exposes them.

> To minimize the latency when receiving each time a new request i need
> to use the Ips from a cache instead of trying to get the ip of the pod
> from the kubernetes API

It's really reinventing the wheel. Every time a `Service` is created (except [Services without selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors)), the corresponding `Endpoints` object is created as well. And in fact it acts exactly like the caching mechanism you need. It keeps track of all IP addresses of `Pods` and gets updated if a `Pod` gets recreated and its IP changes. This way you have a guarantee that it is always up to date. When implementing any cache mechanism you would need to call the kubernetes API anyway, to make sure that a `Pod` with such IP still exists and if it doesn't, what was created instead of it, with what name, with what IP address. Quite bothersome, isn't it ?

**And it is not true that each time you access a `Pod` you need to make a call to kubernetes API** to get its IP address. In fact,`Service` is implemented as a set of **iptables** rules on each node. When the request hits the virtual IP of the `Service` it actually falls into specific **iptables chain** and gets routed by the the kernel to the backend `Pod`. Kubernetes networking is really wide topic, so I recommend you to read about it e.g. using the resources I attached in the end, but not going into unnecessary details it's worth mentioning that each time cluster configuration changes (e.g. some `Pod` is recreated and gets a different IP and the respective `Endpoints` object, that keeps track of `Pods` IPs for the specific `Service`, changes), `kube-proxy` which runs as a container on every node takes care of updating the above mentioned iptables forwarding rules. If running in **iptables mode** (which is the most common implementation) `kube-proxy` configures `Netfilter` chains so the connection is routed directly to the backend container’s endpoint by the node’s kernel.

So API call is made only when the cluster configuration changes so that `kube-proxy` can update iptables rules. Normally when you're accessing the `Pod` via a `Service`, the traffic is routed to backend `Pods` based on current `iptables` rules without a need for asking **kubenetes API** about the IP of such `Pod`.

In fact, [Krishna Chaurasia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5147259/krishna-chaurasia) have already answered your question (shortly but 100% correct) by saying:

> You should not access pod by their IPs. They are not persisted across
> pod restarts.

and

> that's not how K8s work. Requests are forwarded based on the Service
> generally and they are redirected towards the matching pods based on
> label/selectors. – Krishna Chaurasia 4 hours ago

I can only agree with that. And my reasons for "why" have been explained in detail above.

Additional resources:

- [Kubernetes Networking Demystified: A Brief Guide](https://www.stackrox.com/post/2020/01/kubernetes-networking-demystified/)
- [iptables: How Kubernetes Services Direct Traffic to Pods](https://dustinspecker.com/posts/iptables-how-kubernetes-services-direct-traffic-to-pods/)
- [Kubernetes: Service, load balancing, kube-proxy, and iptables](https://rtfm.co.ua/en/kubernetes-service-load-balancing-kube-proxy-and-iptables/)
- [Network overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview) on GCP docs or more specifically [very nice explanation how `kube-proxy` works](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#kube-proxy)